# E series Components and Information

Tags: capacitor, resistors, power-electronics, inductor, zener

What electronic components are made using the E96 and E24 series?
I couldn't find any sources to learn about the E series. Can you please help me?

Comment: I have provided an answer below, but a quick web search shows lots of answers, so I am confused by your statement "I couldn't find any sources"...

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Perhaps take a look at resistor kits, capacitor kits, inductor kits on any of the large distributors.  You'll find loads of information and manufacturers' data sheets and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a huge amount of information available on the E "preferred values" scheme available from a simple web search.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) has a very good article.

The scheme defines spacings based on the fact that tolerances are normally % based (due to physical manufacturing limits), and therefore spacings need to increase accordingly with larger values.  This equates to even spacing when values are expressed on a logarithmic scale, though for various historic reasons a number of the specific values aren't exactly on the ideal values.

It is commonly used with parts whose values span multiple decades of the relevant property.  Resistors, capacitors and inductors are the main examples.

In terms of specifically when E24 & E96 are used, the spacing means E24 is typically used with 5% tolerance (or better) components, whilst E96 is reserved for components with 1% (or better) tolerance.

And in general, given cost and volume factor, you will find that even for precision caps & inductors these will be at E24 (so not many different values have to be stocked), whilst RC and RL adjustments are made with 1% resistors at E96 spacings (as these can be made very cheaply).

Comment: yeah I read about it in Wikipedia but my  professor told me it wrong and kicked me out of the class

Comment: In what way "wrong"?

Comment: @StarLord That’s a problem with the professor, not with you I’d say. And saying to a student that they are wrong without explaining well why is dereliction of a duty of a professor.

Comment: Understood.  If the answer provides what you need, please mark as answered to help others.

Comment: @colintd He asked what components use E96 and E24. I told as in Wikipedia resistors, capacitors, inductors and zener diode.

Comment: @StarLord I've extended the answer to highlight that E24 matches 5% tolerance, and E96 1% tolerance, so those ranges are typically used with components at that tolerance.

Comment: @colintd Can you just tell me what are those basic components, please?

Comment: @StarLord I have updated answer to highlight that in general 1% resistors use E96, whilst even 1% inductors and capacitors tend to stick to E24, because most circuits care about RC and RL values, and it is easier/cheaper to have a few cap / inductor values, with the adjustment of RC & RL done via the resistors

Answer (score 4):

Resistors and capacitors are commonly given values according to an E series, as are inductors and zener diodes.

Resistors can easily be made and are often required to percent tolerances, so all values of E24 are usually available for free issue in design labs. 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8 etc - there are some odd jumps at the bottom end of the decade where two significant figures isn't quite enough to get smooth logarithmic steps. It settles down at the top end of the decade, 6.2, 6.8, 7.5, 8.2, 9.1. Beginners often feel those steps are too big, but they are just the same (approximate) ratio steps as at the 1.1 end!

When you need high tolerance resistors, there are E48, E96 and E192 ranges available, but it's a somewhat moot point whether it's worth buying a resistor from those standard ranges, or just getting the exact value custom made.

Capacitors tend to be a bit coarser. E3 is common, so 1 uF, 2.2 uF, 4.7 uF, I'm sure you'll recognise those values, or interpolated with the E6 values which adds 1.5, 3.3 and 6.8.